# How to pass current parameters to Url.Action in MVC5 C#?

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

How to pass current parameters to Url.Action in MVC5 C#?

viewModel:

```
IndexViewModel
 ->SubViewModel
   ->Option1
```

The parameter is SubViewModel.Option1 in routeValues.

View:

```
Url.Action("Index", this.ViewContext.RouteData.Values)
```

This does not return any route even if route values exists.

Comment: are you asking about parameters in Url.Action?

Comment: What do you mean _The route is SubViewModel.Option1_ (that is not a route!). And the 2nd parameter of `Url.Action()` is an object (or `RouteValueDictionary`), for example `new { id = ViewContext.RouteData.Values["id"] }`

Comment: @AlexiAmni Sorry, I meant parameters.

Comment: so the first parameter in Url.Action is action name ,second one is controller name and third and more are the values of additional parameters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution by using this extension:

```
public static class NvcExtension
{
    public static IDictionary<string, object> ToDictionary(this NameValueCollection col)
    {
        IDictionary<string, object> dict = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        foreach (var k in col.AllKeys)
        {
            dict.Add(k, col.GetValues(k).FirstOrDefault());
        }

        return dict;
    }
}
```

View:

```
Url.Action("Index", new RouteValueDictionary(this.Request.QueryString.ToDictionary()))
```